# Why do both the sre and re modules exist in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have always assumed that when I saw people mention the `sre` module, it was a typo and they actually meant `re`.

Today, I accidentally typed `import sre` into the interpreter and was surprised that it worked. I decided to dig a bit more into what the `sre` module was via `help(sre)` and... everything about what it does is the exact same as `re`.

Why do both modules exist? Which came first? Why was the second created? Is one getting deprecated and/or removed (is it already gone in Python 3? I don't have a Python 3 interpreter on this computer to check with.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re` was introduced in Python 1.5 (using Philip Hazel's PCRE code), as a better thing than `regexp` from Python 0.9.0 (removed in Python 1.5), and `regex` from Python 0.9.5 (which went to undocumented in Python 2.0 and was later removed).

Python 2.0 added a new, Unicode-compatible implementation called `sre` by Fredrik Lundh of SecretLabs.  The previous version was kept as a module called `pre` (the Python 2.0 documentation said that's because the new `sre` "may run into stack limitations for some patterns" at that time), and the `re` module could be set to point to either: usually `sre` but distros could set it to `pre` if they wanted.  So in theory if you wanted to make *sure* you were getting the Unicode compatible implementation in Python 2.0 you had to explicitly `import sre`, but I don't know of any distro where `import re` was not equivalent to this.

And then Python 2.4 removed `pre` because the stack limitations had been addressed in `sre`, and you could import either `re` or `sre` and it would be equivalent.

Then Python 2.5 deprecated `sre` (which was now just an alias to `re`) and Python 3.0 removed it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is deprecated. When you did `help(sre)`, you must have seen this line:

```
DESCRIPTION
    This file is only retained for backwards compatibility.
    It will be removed in the future.  sre was moved to re in version 2.5.
```

So it's used for code that is designed for Python <2.5, but it is now replaced by `re`.

Furthermore, it was removed:

```
# Python 3
>>> import sre
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'sre'
```

Comment: I didn't. `help` just dumped out the entire string so I only saw the last ~50 lines of it. So this answers some of my questions, but I'm still curious - why did `sre` ever exist? I was under the impression that `regex` from Python 1 got replaced with `re` in Python 2... where does `sre` fit in with this?

Comment: `sre` was the beginning of regex. It just sounds like they updated it with a new module that probably performed much better. It's like Python 2 and Python 3